# Firefox does not provide all surface display options for getDisplayMedia()

Tags: javascript, firefox

the spec says:

> the user agent MUST still offer the user unlimited choice of any
> display surface.

https://www.w3.org/TR/screen-capture/#dom-mediadevices

But Firefox only offers "Window" or "Screen", and not the browser tab contents like Chrome/Edge.  Am I missing something?  Is there a way to capture only the tab?

Answer (score 1):

You're right. Firefox (and Safari 16) currently allows windows and screens **only** to be captured with `getDisplayMedia()`. Chrome allows window, screens, and tabs.

Note that you can detect afterwards which display surface type (tab, window, screen) the user picked thanks to the `displaySurface` track setting.

```js
// Prompt the user to share a tab, a window or a screen.
const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia();
const [track] = stream.getVideoTracks();
const displaySurface = track.getSettings().displaySurface;

if (displaySurface == "browser") {
  // User picked a tab.
} else if (displaySurface == "window") {
  // User picked a window.
} else if (displaySurface == "monitor") {
  // User picked a screen.
}
```